# Enterprise Library 5.0: Writing log to file without XML configuration

Tags: c#, .net, logging, enterprise-library

There is some code for logging to file. I dont using app.config

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      MyLogger.Write("This is message error", "My Category");
      Console.ReadKey();
   }      
}

public static class MyLogger
{
   static readonly LogWriterImpl _writer;

   static MyLogger()
   {
      TextFormatter formatter = new TextFormatter
            ("Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}" +
            "Message: {message}{newline}" +
            "Category: {category}{newline}");

      var logFileListener = new Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener
      (
         "c:\\messages.log", "----------", "----------", formatter
      );


      LogSource mainLogSource = new LogSource("MainLogSource", SourceLevels.All);
      mainLogSource.Listeners.Add(logFileListener);
      LogSource nonExistantLogSource = new LogSource("Empty");

      IDictionary<string, LogSource> traceSources = new Dictionary<string, LogSource>();
      traceSources.Add("Error", mainLogSource);
      traceSources.Add("Debug", mainLogSource);


      _writer = new LogWriterImpl
      (
         new Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.ILogFilter[0],
         traceSources,
         nonExistantLogSource,
         nonExistantLogSource,
         mainLogSource,
         "Error",
         false,
         true
         );
   }

   public static void Write(string message)
   {
      Write(message, "Error");
   }

   public static void Write(string message, string category)
   {
      LogEntry entry = new LogEntry();

      entry.Categories.Add(category);
      entry.Message = message;

      _writer.Write(entry);
   }
}
```

This program work without errors but it don't create log file **c:\messages.log** and don't write log entity. Where is the error? I don't want using application config file in my project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a couple of reasons (at least!) why you are not seeing any logging:

1. The categories that are configured for logging are "Error" and "Debug" but when you call `MyLogger.Write` you are passing a category of "My Category"
2. There could be a permission problem.  Writing to the root of the drive is frequently restricted

As an aside, you should probably store the reference to `LogWriterImpl` as the base class `LogWriter`.

As another aside, instead of using the logging classes directly it is preferable to [use the Fluent Configuration API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx#fluent_api_logging) which was released as part of version 5.0.  It makes this type of configuration much simpler.  As an example:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

builder.ConfigureLogging()
       .WithOptions
         .DoNotRevertImpersonation()
       .LogToCategoryNamed("My Category")
         .SendTo.FlatFile("MyMessages")
           .FormatWith(new FormatterBuilder()
             .TextFormatterNamed("Text Formatter")
               .UsingTemplate("Timestamp: {timestamp}...{newline})}"))
             .ToFile("c:\\messages.log");

var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current 
  = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```

It's also more maintainable and supportable. E.g. there is less chance that there won't be breaking implementation changes like when `LogWriter` was made abstract as part of version 5.

Comment: It works good with this code: **Logger.Write("This is Error Message", "My Category");**